# How can I get the value inside of an NSTextField?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, double, nstextfield

My NSTextField contains doubles like "1.67" or "0.05" etc.

When I try the following:

```
console.log([priceChange doubleValue]); //priceChange is an NSTextField

    //Apply styles
    if([priceChange doubleValue] > 0)
        [priceChange setTextColor:[NSColor greenColor]];
    else if([priceChange doubleValue] < 0)
        [priceChange setTextColor:[NSColor redColor]];
    else if([priceChange doubleValue] == 0)
        [priceChange setTextColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
```

priceChange is equal to 0 always, even when the value is something else. How can I properly get the value of priceChange?

Comment: console.log() ? Is this Objective-C or Objective-J ? Cappuccino or Cocoa?

Comment: Just a thought, but is `priceChange` nil, somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is precisely what `NSNumberFormatter` is for. Give your field a suitable formatter (easy to add/setup in IB), and -objectValue will start returning an `NSNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `[[priceChange stringValue] floatValue]`. Also make sure there is nothing other than whitespace before the number in the string, or floatValue will return 0.

Comment: `[priceChange stringValue] floatValue]` results in NaN

Comment: What is the value of the text field? You could try doubleValue if it is too big to fit in a float.